# Plotting graphs using dash (Python package)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have been trying to make a report using the dash package in Python, but there is an issue with the code starting from how I defined the figure. The data file has 2 columns with headers 'Name' and 'marks' where the 'Name' column is filled with string values and 'mark' with integers.

`Debug = False` as I am running this code on Spyder.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Karthik\Desktop\personal\python\data.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Dash Tutorials'),
    dcc.Graph(id='example',
        figure={
            'data':[{'x': Data['Name'],'y':Data['marks'],'type'='line', 'name'='boats'} 
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Basic Dash Example'
            }
           } 
        )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: "theres an issue with the code" - what's the issue?

Comment: im not quite sure myself, the code analysis says its due to invalid syntax(pyflakes E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line has invalid syntax:

```
'data':[{'x': Data['Name'],'y':Data['marks'],'type'='line', 'name'='boats'}
```

Entries in dictionary literals are defined like `key: value`, *not* `key = value`, so you should change it to this:

```
'data':[{'x': Data['Name'],'y': Data['marks'],'type': 'line', 'name': 'boats'}
```

If you want to use the `key=value` syntax anyway, the `dict` class supports it:

```
'data': [dict(
    x=Data['Name'],
    y=Data['marks'],
    type='line',
    name='boats'
)]
```